# How to get the response from a modal dialog?

Tags: java, android

I currently have this:

```
Builder yesandno = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);           
yesandno.setTitle("QuickResponse");
yesandno.setMessage(message);
yesandno.setPositiveButton("YES", null);
yesandno.setNegativeButton("NO", null);
yesandno.show();
```

How should I go by setting an event listener that will capture if the user clicked YES or NO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `setPositiveButton()` and `setNegativeButton()` instead of passing in `null` you should pass in a [`DialogInterface.OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html).

For example:

```
yesandno.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //User clicked yes!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do something like:

```
yesandno.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // User clicked yes
    }
});
yesandno.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // User clicked no
    }
});
```

and do whatever you want in the button callbacks.